# How to save textField.text data and persist them when moving between view controllers?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, persistence

I have built a multi-step sign up with 3 different view controllers.

```
VC1: Email, pass, confirm pass text fields then press next to VC2
VC2: First, middle, last name then press next to VC 3
VC3: Address, city, state, zipcode -> Complete sign up.
```

I would like to know how I can persist the textField.text data when moving between these View Controllers.

So, when I filled up VC2 but go back to VC1, then back to VC2, my VC2 fields are reset and are blank, how do I save these fields so that when I go back to VC2, they are saved and populated?

UserDefaults? And saving them to a model when the back button is pressed? Is there a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: You should create a dictionary and pass the dictionary beween VCs.That will be a better way rather than storing each field in Userdefault

Comment: We need some more information about how you've set up your view controllers and how you're pushing the next view controller onto the screen. Are you using segues?

Answer (score 0):

So if you use segues to navigate between screens like `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ID_HERE", sender: self)`. I would recommend to pass the data from VC1 to VC2 to VC3 and if you go back you pass the inserted data to the previous ViewController.

To pass from VC1 to VC2 you can use the prepareForSegue function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ID_HERE"{
        let destVC = segue.destination as! NextViewController
        destVC.variable = self.variable
    }
}
```

To pass the data back from VC2 to VC1 do the following:

Create a Protocol:

```
protocol VC2Delegate {
func passData(passedString: String)
}
```

Add the Protocol to VC1

```
Class VC1: : UIViewController, VC2Delegate{}
```

and implement the function from the Protocol:

```
func passData(passedString: String){ 
   //Write the String in your TextField or whatever
}
```

and add the following line to the prepareForSegue function

```
destVC.VC2Delegate = self
```

and you need the VC2Delegate variable in VC2:

```
var VC2Delegate : VC2Delegate?
```

and inside the VC2 you call the passData function after the user clicked the save button or for example in the viewWillDisappear

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    VC2Delegate?.passData(passedString: String)
}
```